# Error em Node.js Module.js 472 throw err;

Tags: node.js

Estou criando uma **API** em node, para requisição com meu aplicativo. Mas aparece este erro, alegando que essa pasta não existe, mas no código não estou chamando ela em lugar nenhum.

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ramon Lopes\Documents\API\NodeApi.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:148:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

Comment: Como você tá rodando o servidor?

Comment: Igor.araujo, rodo o servidor com os comandos normais **(nodemon)Node.js e mongod(MongoDB)**. Mas a ajuda do Collins foi suficiente. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

> npm start

e depois:

> ng serve

Comment: Perfetio Collins, ate hoje não tinha conseguido , ams executei o teu ensinamento e deu certo.